# How to detect memory leaks in a dll library?

Tags: delphi, memcheck

I have `d7` and `dll` library. How can i attach the `memcheck` to that library, 
that I could detect memory leaks in it?

Comment: Personally I use FastMM to do this.

Comment: How to make fastmm detect leaks in a dll, not in the app that uses it?

Comment: Just include it in your DLL and configure it to report leaks

Comment: Well i cannot make it work. I have compiled both the dll and the client app with fastmm4 unit, also with the options I think are revelant (define ShareMM, ShareMMIfLibrary, AttemptToUseSharedMM, FullDebugMode) and it reports only the client leaks ...

Comment: If you use ShareMM it's hard to separate client and DLL leaks.

Comment: Make sure you rebuild the application once you add FastMM, not just compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Expecially for memory leaks in dll's (IIS Web application) I am using Eurekalog which also handels Memory leaks and shows where they occur!